# How to create Pagination , if there are some conditions(Where caluse) in your mysql Query?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a query like this :

```
     $pagenumber = get_page_number(); // I'll get the pagenumber by a method wich runs when user click's on page numbers , for example : 2 or 3 or whatevere user clicks.


     //Now , I'll make A Limit caluse : 

     $limit = $pagenumber.",10"; // limit the page to show 10 result  => example : LIMIT 2,10

     $sql = "SELECT * From doctors LIMIT $limit";
     --> after this , I show the result which is by my on way (echo a div for every result );
```

It was a cool pagination , which was working fine.

---

But the problem is , when there is A **WHERE** in my query , mysql gets confused and I dont know what to do

Consider this :

```
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE `firstname` LIKE '$firstname' LIMIT $limit";
```

So , its not working:((

I know the problem is "WHERE " clause , because when user clicks on a page number , my **$limit** will be for example : *2,10*
 and my query will be this :

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM doctors Where firstname LIKE '$firstname' LIMIT 2,10";
```

Here there is A condition (WHERE firstname ....) 
How mysql even knows where to start searching ?(by starting point , I mean if "LIMIT x,y" x is starting point)

How mysql knows what I mean by "LIMIT 2,10".

Where does placed  ***2*** in my table ?(when there is a condition);

If there is NO condition , **2** means record number 21 ( am I right ?), of course if offset is 10 ;  (LIMIT 2,10) ;

is that Right?

But , what if there is A WHERE clause , ??????

Now what is that starting point ?(2????)

If you want more specific details , feel free to ask(I think I explained percisely)
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: You must `order by` your result set. The rows then have a definite order and by this MySQL simply "counts away" rows, until it reaches your start point and then gives you the number of rows you requested.

Comment: you can't use the pagenumber as limit like this, the limits indicates after which result row  you want to start. i.e. 1,10 would give you resultrow 2-11; 2,10 would give you back resultrow 3-12

Comment: so what ? there is no solotion ?
how Internet works so ?(google , yahoo, this whole searching site?)

Comment: I don't think MySQL gets confused; judging by this and your previous question, you seem confused by the fact that a database has no inherent concept of record ordering other than when supplied by you in the form of an ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

```
$pagesize = 10;
$start = ($page) * $pagesize;  // assuming you're passing in 0 based pages, if they're 1 base, do a $page -1

$sql = "SELECT * FROM doctors Where firstname LIKE '$firstname' ORDER BY lastname LIMIT $start,$pagesize";
```

You need to order your result set in order for limit to make sense.  Also, start needs to account for page size.

Comment: Your answer is just like my own question :(
with this whole explanation , no one gets the problem 
brother, Consider if you click on page number 3 , ok ?
your $start will be : (3-1)*10 = 20 , OK ????

Comment: now , mysql will search in the database , from record number 20 ,OK ?
where mysql stops? After finding 10 records OK ?
and maybe the 10th record will be at the end of the table (not exactly the end , somewere near end) , OK ?
now , if you click on page number 4 , where will be the starting point for mysql to start searching? the last record from your last click ? Or simply, record number 30 ?  if its 30 , then there will be some similar records to show ? huh ?

Comment: @andy - We're trying to help you here.  You might want to scale back the attitude.  If no one is understanding your question, you need to add more explanation.  Perhaps add sample data and what you would like returned with each request.  In answer to this "if you click on page number 4 , where will be the starting point for mysql to start searching? the last record from your last click ? Or simply, record number 30 ?" - Yes, it will start on the 30th record.  What is "your last click"